# Exception thrown when retrieving data from database when grouping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, exception, mysql.data

I'm trying to retrieve accounting periods from a `MySql` database using entity framework but keep running into an `InvalidCastException` exception.

This is the linq statement below:

```
var periodList = (from pd in _context.perioddates
                 join p in _context.periods on pd.PeriodId equals p.PeriodId
                 orderby pd.PeriodDate1 descending
                 group new { p, pd } by p.PeriodId into pdg
                 select pdg.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

This query should give me a list of periods and their start dates, leaving out their period end dates. However it throws the following:

> TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

The inner exception being:

> InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
>
> > This exception was originally thrown at this call stack: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetByte(int)

The period table is Modeled as follows:

```
public partial class period
{
    public byte PeriodId { get; set; } // TinyInt Unsigned
    public long Period1 { get; set; } // Int Unsigned
    public string PeriodName { get; set; } // VarChar
}
```

And the period table looks like this:

```
public partial class perioddate
{
    public int PeriodDateId { get; set; } // SmallInt Unsigned
    public DateTime PeriodDate1 { get; set; } // DateTime
    public byte VariantId { get; set; } // Tiny Int
    public byte PeriodId { get; set; } // Tiny int
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it's throwing this exception? Why would it have a problem drawing `tinyints` from the db when using grouped data and load perfectly fine when pulling info straight? I'm a bit baffled at this.

Much appreciated in advance.

***Edit:***

When I say 'pulling straight' I mean a query that pulls all records from the database as is, without a group. In this instance, that would be:

```
var periodList = (from pd in _context.perioddates
                  join p in _context.periods on pd.PeriodId equals p.PeriodId
                  orderby pd.PeriodDate1 descending
                  select new PeriodModel()
                  {
                      PeriodId = p.PeriodId,
                      Period = p.Period1,
                      PeriodDateId = pd.PeriodDateId,
                      PeriodDate = pd.PeriodDate1
                  }).ToList();
```

This query will work but it includes closing dates as well.

Comment: Hey Tim  `when pulling info straight` - can you please add the query that does work? it can help narrow down the problem

Comment: Try `group  p  by p.PeriodId into pdg`

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I've made the requested clarification at the bottom of the question. Please take a look.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Hey. Thanks for the suggestion. I gave that a shot and it still threw me out with the same exception. Maybe it's a bug in the MySql.Data dll?

Comment: `PeriodId` in one table is unsigned and the other signed? Check all your data types match properly

Comment: @ Charlieface sorry that was a mistake on my part. All integer fields are unsigned

Comment: Then you should use unsigned types in C# also, such as `ulong` and `uint` and `ushort`. Also `unsigned int` should be mapped to `uint`